# Complicated regex and possible simple way to do it

Tags: java, regex

I have to check if the input matches this format.

The input can either come like this

```
([0-9])(%)([0-9])
```

(for example 5%7 is valid) or more than once but in this format:

```
([0-9])(%)([0-9])(;)([0-9])(%)([0-9])
```

So a valid input would be

```
5%6;4%7
```

and I have to specify how many times the sequence

```
([0-9])(%)([0-9])
```

comes, but it has to appear at least once. So ,for example, if the max times it appears is 3 then a valid input would be :

```
5%7;2%7;2%8 or 5%7;7%7 or 1%7
```

I'd really appreciate some help with this, as I am not too experienced with regex.

Comment: You need to wrap the semi-colon with the digit%digit pattern with a group and set a quantifier of your choice to it. Say, to allow 1 or more use `[0-9]%[0-9](?:;[0-9]%[0-9])*` with `.matches()`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so if I want to repeat a max of 4 times then I would type [0-9]%[0-9](?:;[0-9]%[0-9]){3}